# how to add a logarithmic widget to plotly scatter plot in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling with getting the code to work for this log widget I want to add to my interactive plot in shiny. I am able to modify the graphs x and y axis to a log scale by adding `log(dat()[[input$yvrbl]])` to the server coder

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive({
    log(dat()[[input$yvrbl]])
  })
  
  y <- reactive({
    log(dat()[[input$yvrbl]])
  })
```

I was able to create the widgets on the ui code as well. I am still unable to transform the data to the log version based on whether or not the widget is checked. I tried making a separate reactive expression to host the changed log version of the x and y axis depending on an if statement. Please let me know what else I can do.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# set working directory
setwd("~/BDSWD")

#read data
gm <- read_csv("gapminder_clean.csv")


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,offset = 4, titlePanel("Explore Gapminder Data with Shiny")),
  headerPanel('Graphs'),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput('plot')
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    #variable selection for x-axis
    selectInput(inputId ='xvrbl', #The input slot that will be used to access the value.
                label = 'X-Axis Variable', #Display label for the control, or NULL for no label.
                choices = colnames(gm), #List of values to select from
                selected = 'CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)'
    ),
    
    checkboxInput(inputId = "LogX", 
                  label = "Log Transform", 
                  value = FALSE),
    
    #variable selection for y-axis
    selectInput(inputId ='yvrbl', #The input slot that will be used to access the value.
                label = 'Y-Axis Variable', #Display label for the control, or NULL for no label.
                choices = colnames(gm), #List of values to select from
                selected = 'gdpPercap'
    ),
    
    checkboxInput(inputId = "LogY", 
                  label = "Log Transform", 
                  value = FALSE),
    
    #date range - slider
    sliderInput(inputId = "time",
                label = "Years",
                min = min(gm$Year),
                max = max(gm$Year),
                step = 5,
                value = c(min(gm$Year),max(gm$Year)))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive({
    dat()[[input$xvrbl]]
  })
  
  y <- reactive({
    dat()[[input$yvrbl]]
  })
  
  dat <- reactive({
    subset(gm, Year %in% input$time)
  })
  
  lgrthmc <- reactive({
    if(isTRUE(input$LogY)) {
      y <- reactive({
        log(dat()[[input$yvrbl]])
      })
    } else {}
    
    if(isTRUE(input$LogX)) {
      x <- reactive({
        log(dat()[[input$xvrbl]])
      })
    } else {}
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      x = x(),
      y = y(),
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers",
      color = dat()$continent
    ) %>%
      layout(
        title = 'Gapminder Dataset', 
        plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6", 
        xaxis = list(title = input$xvrbl), 
        yaxis = list(title = input$yvrbl), 
        legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Continent </b>'))
        )
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping `reactive`s inside a `reactive` you could achieve your desired result by adding an `if` inside your `reactive`s, e.g.

Note: I slightly adjusted the subsetting of your data to take the `sliderInput` into account.

```
x <- reactive({
    x <- dat()[[input$xvrbl]]
    if (input$LogX) x <- log(x)
    return(x)
  })
```

```r
library(gapminder)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

gm <- gapminder |> rename(Year = year)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3, offset = 4, titlePanel("Explore Gapminder Data with Shiny")),
  headerPanel("Graphs"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    # variable selection for x-axis
    selectInput(
      inputId = "xvrbl", # The input slot that will be used to access the value.
      label = "X-Axis Variable", # Display label for the control, or NULL for no label.
      choices = colnames(gm), # List of values to select from
      selected = "lifeExp"
    ),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "LogX", 
                  label = "Log Transform", 
                  value = FALSE),
    # variable selection for y-axis
    selectInput(
      inputId = "yvrbl", # The input slot that will be used to access the value.
      label = "Y-Axis Variable", # Display label for the control, or NULL for no label.
      choices = colnames(gm), # List of values to select from
      selected = "gdpPercap"
    ),
    checkboxInput(
      inputId = "LogY",
      label = "Log Transform",
      value = FALSE
    ),

    # date range - slider
    sliderInput(
      inputId = "time",
      label = "Years",
      min = min(gm$Year),
      max = max(gm$Year),
      step = 5,
      value = range(gm$Year)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive({
    x <- dat()[[input$xvrbl]]
    if (input$LogX) x <- log(x)
    return(x)
  })

  y <- reactive({
    y <- dat()[[input$yvrbl]]
    if (input$LogY) y <- log(y)
    return(y)
  })

  dat <- reactive({
    subset(gm, Year >= input$time[[1]], Year <= input$time[[2]])
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      x = x(),
      y = y(),
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers",
      color = dat()$continent
    )
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6593
```

[image]